# JQuery AJAX upload file does not work with files more than 10 MB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I've been stumped with this issue for the past 3 hours. I've looked at countless guides and posts to no avail.

I have a system where users are able to upload files. Once they select a file, I want to upload the file (via PHP file) and show the user the upload progress. I've tried to do this using `$.ajax` (using FormData) and JQuery Form plugin. They both work with smaller files that are less than 10 MB, but I've found that when I try to upload a file that's more than 10 MB my PHP file receives none of the information (`$_POST` or `$_FILE`).

How can I fix this issue, or how can I allow users to upload files and show them an accurate upload progress bar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your `php.ini` maybe it's the `max_size` setting

Comment: ^^ As @Tsuna stated .. Check the `ini` file and raise the limits. IE `upload_max_filesize = 20M` and  `post_max_size = 21M`

Comment: @Tsuna hmm... I checked and it says maximum is 8MB and I can't edit the `php.ini`. how else is it possible for me to make a progress bar without using POST?

Comment: @k97513 what do you mean by your can't edit `php.init`?

Comment: @Tsuna I am using shared hosting and as a result I do not have access to the `php.ini`.

Comment: you should, if really cannot then I believe you have to contact your host provider

Comment: @Tsuna I will. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check two vars in your PHP script:

`ini_get('post_max_size')`, `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` and if the user is able to upload multiple files `ini_get('max_file_uploads')`. If one or all limits are below your expectations you should raise them in your php.ini

Edit: Added upload_max_filesize to the list.

Comment: hmm... I checked and it says maximum is 8MB and I can't edit the `php.ini`. how else is it possible for me to make a progress bar without using POST?

Comment: What do you mean by "make a progress bar without using POST"? You don't want to receive the data the user is uploading on your server?

Comment: well seeing as that I can't modify the `php.ini` to accommodate for larger files, how else can I upload the file?

Comment: The main problem is that if you don't use `$_POST` you are not able to upload the files at all. Can't you just contact your hoster?

Comment: I will. Thanks for your help.